# html elements not animating after correctly configuring animate css and wow js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, wow.js

Link to my live website, `https://travelaja.vercel.app/`

I followed the animate.css and wow.js documentation on how to configure the libraries to work and correctly did that after initially misconfiguring the script.

I added the animate.css and wow.js using their CDN,

```
<link
   rel="stylesheet"
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js" integrity="sha512-Eak/29OTpb36LLo2r47IpVzPBLXnAMPAVypbSZiZ4Qkf8p/7S/XRG5xp7OKWPPYfJT6metI+IORkR5G8F900+g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>new WOW().init();</script>
```

The animate.css is added in the head tag while the script tags are added at the bottom of the page.

I added the classnames, `wow slideInLeft` inside of the `section` (this is the second immediately after the hero section) with ``` about-us `` class. When I inspected it, I observed it had the visibility of hidden and then visible when I scrolled to the location with the animated class added and the animated name of ``` slideInLeft```, but the only issue I am having is that the animation itself is not visible or has no effect.

I checked a GitHub issue and someone suggested removing the overflow-x: hidden on the body or HTML which I observed I had and removed but the issue persisted.

I was initially facing `WOW is not defined issue`, which I fixed by placing the script at the end of the page and the error was gone.

Comment: Dear read the documentation for the version you are using.
I tested this class animate__animated animate__bounce on the link you put in your question and works. This is the documentation link https://animate.style/ then got to basic usage. for slide left this is the class animate_animated animate__slideInLeft

Comment: @Andam, thanks for the response. I tried this just now and it worked perfectly.

I was following the instructions from https://wowjs.uk/docs.html earlier and that is what misled me, they were not not using the "animate__animated animate__bounce" kind of classnames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following the instruction from, "https://wowjs.uk/docs.html" and the way the classes was being used was quite different, I switched to using this instead, "https://animate.style/" and added the wow class as well and it worked just fine.

A snippet of the former/wrong usage.

```
<div class="section-1 wow slideInLeft">
    your content
</div>
```

A snippet of the new/right usage.

```
<div class="section-1 wow animate__animated animate__slideInLeft">
    your content
</div>
```